# What statistics can compare dataset with shared values from same data source?

Tags: anova, t-test, independence

Note- The following question was first posted on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673501/) and I was advised in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7584099?noredirect=1) to post on the Stats Stackexchange. Please forgive me if reposting in this way is considered improper.

I have a dataset structured as follows:

[image]

I have split the data depending on the `Structure` column containing either "A", "B" or both as below:

[image]

In this dataset, if the `Structure` column contains "A", the observed value is copied in column `Contains A`. Similarly if the `Structure` column contains "B", the value is copied in column `Contains B` and if the `Structure` column contains both "A" and "B" then the value is copied in the column `Contains A & B`.

**Question:** What statistics parameter/analysis can you use to compare these three groups of data (`Contains A`, `Contains B`, `Contains A & B`) where some points are shared (and hence not independent) to show if there is any difference between these? Is there any test like a t-test or ANOVA which can be used to compare these three despite them sharing data points?

Comment: You need to have _disjoint_ categories. Not knowing what the A's and B's are, the mechanism giving rise to the various structures, or the purpose of your proposed test, it is difficult to speculate how to do that meaningfully: Maybe 'Mostly A' 800 and 'Mostly B' 110 (ignoring AB). Maybe `A & no B', 'B & no A' and 'Both A & B'. Maybe 'Short' or 'Long' sequence, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. AB are parts of a chemical structure. So when structure A is present or structure B is present as a part of a bigger molecule. Unfortunately I do not think classifying it as Mostly A or Mostly B can be done in chemistry, as the can have a dramatic effect on the overall structure. Note there can also be C but for the purpose of brevity I restricted to A and B. Is there no statistical test which can compare non-disjoint/intersecting categories?

Comment: There is no _reputable_ test do do that. You need to get that idea out of your head and think about what a logical comparison would be in your situation. // There would be serious logical and technical difficulties doing 2-sample tests on groups that are not disjoint.  It seems strange to compare Manhattan with New York city, when the comparison should be be between Manhattan and the _rest_ of  NYC. Or to compare Women with Humans instead of Women with Men.// Also subjects that are in both groups destroy the assumed independence of the two samples.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will definitely reconsider how to do my analysis, but a bit disappointed that there is no straightforward test to do it.